# How do I make a select list of time from 00:00 to 23:55 without DST?

Tags: php, unix, timestamp, dst

I am trying to create two select lists both filled with the same times. It's basically for the user to select a start time and end time. I've calculated these as my times:

```
$startTime = 0; //00:00
$endTime =  86100; //23:55'
$now = $startTime;
```

and then I'm incrementing like this:

```
$now += 300;
```

where 300 = 5 minutes, therefore I'm incrementing the time by 5 minutes during each loop.

Therefore, my select lists should look like this:

```
00:00
00:05
00:10
...
...
23:45
23:50
23:55
```

The whole thing works, apart from the actual times being printed. I am getting this:

```
1:00
1:05
...
...
00:45
00:50
00:55
```

I suspect the problem is the fact we are now in Daylight Saving Time here in the UK. How should I therefore tackle this problem?

This is my actual method:

```
public function timeSelectList()
{

    $startTime = 0; //00:00
    $endTime =  86100; //23:55'
    $now = $startTime;

    $startSelectList = '<label for="startSelect">Start Time</label><select name="startSelect" id="startSelect">';
    $endSelectList = '<label for="endSelect">End Time</label><select name="endSelect" id="endSelect">';

    while($now <= $endTime)
    {
        if($now == 61200)//17:00
        {
            $startSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'" selected="selected">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
            $endSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
        }
        else if($now == 64800)//18:00
        {
            $startSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
            $endSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'" selected="selected">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            $startSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
            $endSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
        }
        $now += 300; //increment 5 minutes (300 seconds = 5 minutes
    }

    $startSelectList .= '</select>';
    $endSelectList .= '</select>';

    return $startSelectList.$endSelectList;
}
```

Comment: You don't use any time/date related function, so I guess that is not your problem, mind posting entire code?

Comment: You're passing in time(0), corresponds to Jan 1/1970 UTC. But with timezones taken into account, it'll be outputting your server's time value, probably back in 1969 somewhere, or a few hours AFTER midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write a function that will convert seconds into hours/minutes?

```
function secToTime($seconds = 0) {
    $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
    $minutes = floor($seconds/60)%60;
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I don't understand the conditional return statement. Can you explain what's happening there? I plugged in 64800 and it printed out 18:1080. 

I think this function is something I'm looking for since the actual date isn't that important. I just want to convert seconds to the corresponding hours and minutes.

Comment: for minutes, you need to do floor(($seconds%3600)/60);

Comment: Sorry about that.  I messed up my minute calculation.

Comment: `return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);`

Comment: @webarto excellent!  I didn't realize I could pad the string that way.  Thank you.

Comment: lol, Crash you keep making mistakes. You put $minutes twice inside the sprintf function.

Comment: I guess that's what happens when I should be working but surfing StackOverflow instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the default timezone to UTC (which doesn't use DST):

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

Comment: Would this function be affected when we turn our clocks backwards 1 hour in October?

Comment: No - UTC is never affected by daylight savings time changes (forwards or backwards)

Answer (score 1):

By setting `$now` to 0 and then using it in `date('H:i', $now)` you are asking PHP to tell you what hour and minute it was in your current timezone when [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) started. This is why @TheOx's solution should work.

I would recommend either going with something like @Crashspeeder suggested or, if you actually need the time of a specific date something like this:

```
$now = strtotime('midnight today'); //or whatever date you need
$endTime = strtotime('midnight tomorrow'); 

while($now < $endtime){
    //your code here
    $now += 300;
}
```

Another suggestion is to use a javascript timepicker like [this one](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) (uses jQuery) and just worry about processing the result in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
function timeSelectList()
{

    $startTime = 0;
    $endTime =  86400;
    $now = $startTime;

    while($now < $endTime)
    {
        $h = floor($now / 3600);
        $m =  ($now - ($h * 3600)) / 60;
        $x .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $m).'</option>';
        $now += 300;
    }

    return 
    '<label for="startSelect">Start Time</label><select name="startSelect" id="startSelect">'.$x.'</select>
    <label for="endSelect">End Time</label><select name="endSelect" id="endSelect">'.$x.'</select>';
}
```